# Dispose Xamarin Forms Views/Pages?

Tags: xamarin.forms, dispose

How to completely dispose Xamarin Forms Pages, their child views and respective data bindings ?

Comment: Hi , could you share some code to explain this ? It depends on the detail scene .

Comment: Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack collect all pushed pages... Its weird and unwanted behaviour... iOS dispose, Android doesn't... Best way manualy dispose last page when page backed (OnDisappearing).

Comment: @NuriYILMAZ - Unfortunately, `OnDisappearing` of page (A) is also called when a new page (B) is pushed on top of the current page (A) - so you should not dispose there - page (A) may become visible again when page (B) is popped. The page lifecycle does not include any event that tells you "this page is no longer needed". Would have to have a `NavigationPage` containing the pages, and add logic to it.

Answer (score 4):

**About disposing Xamarin Forms Pages** ,if using **[NavigationPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical)** as root page in xamarin forms project .There is an easy way to close the page.

*The NavigationPage class provides a hierarchical navigation experience where the user is able to navigate through pages, forwards and backwards, as desired. The class implements navigation as a last-in, first-out (LIFO) stack of Page objects.*

To move from one page to another, an application will push a new page onto the navigation stack, where it will become the active page, as shown in the following diagram:

[image]

To return back to the previous page, the application will pop the current page from the navigation stack, and the new topmost page becomes the active page, as shown in the following diagram:

[image]

Navigation methods are exposed by the Navigation property on any Page derived types. These methods provide the ability to push pages onto the navigation stack, to pop pages from the navigation stack, and to perform stack manipulation.

> their child views and respective data bindings

If need to deal with their child views and respective data bindings , you know that there is **[Page notification events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/app-lifecycle#page-notification-events)** can deal with that .

- **PageDisappearing** - raised when a page is about to disappear from the screen.

This event can be used in scenarios where you want to track pages as they appear on screen.

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    // deal with view modle or child views here
}
```

Comment: I am building a video conferencing app. Suppose I have two pages A & B. Page B has a list of OpenTokSubscriberViews that represents all the participants of video chat. When navigating from A to B using PushModelAsync(), it creates a list of Subscribers and set its binding to <tok:OpenTokSubscriberView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" BackgroundColor="Gray"  x:Name="mainSubcriberView"  StreamId="{Binding Path=StreamIdCollection, Source={x:Static tokService:CrossOpenTok.Current}}"     /> like this. Now on iOS, I go back and fourth between A & B repeatedly.

Comment: iOS works well, but if i do the same on Android, it throws an exception saying that "It can not reactivate instance of OpenTokSubscriberViewRenderer" from native handle. I just removed StreamId binding property and replaced it with "", it did not crash. It seems that PopAsync() on Page B does not clear/dispose Page B completely and release "StreamIdCollection" before next navigation to Page B is started and it crashes. That's why I am making sure Page B ,its views and bindings are gone. I tried setting ListView to null on OnDisAppearing() but it did not work.

Comment: @AliRaza If crash in Android , you can free the video stream before `PopAsync()` on Page B .

Comment: I cannot access "SV" in codebehind file. Do you have any idea how to do that?<syncfusion:SfListView  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StreamIdCollection, Source={x:Static tokService:CrossOpenTok.Current}}" >
           <syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                   <Frame  Padding="1">
                   <tok:OpenTokSubscriberView x:Name="SV" StreamId="{Binding .}"/>
                </Frame>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
           </syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
       </syncfusion:SfListView>

Comment: @AliRaza You can not get the items by `x:Name` , because they are inside itemsoure . Have  a look at this [Tapped Event](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/listview/working-with-sflistview#tapped-event) with shared sample code , you will know how to get `ItemSource` in `SFListView` .