# When are .NET MAUI (Xamarin Forms) pages/custom views destroyed?

Tags: xamarin.android, maui

I'm new to Xamarin/.NET MAUI application development. I started to develop a sample .NET MAUI application for Android device.
I'm trying to understand how/when a page and my custom view are destroyed (disposed of).  I read some web pages but I can't really understand how things work in .NET MAUI (or Xamarin).

I have three pages: `MainPage`, `SecondPage`, `TestMapPage`.
`SecondPage` has a button that navigates to `TestMapPage`. It instantiates a `TestMapPage` object and passes it to `Navigation.PushAsync()`.
`TestMapPage` contains a custom view `TestMapView`, which is rendered by my custom view renderer `TestMapViewRenderer`. I create a `MapView` object (from `Naxam.Mapbox.Droid`) in the renderer and show the map in `TestMapPage`. The map appears on the emulator and it works fine.

I thought that `SecondPage`, `TestMapPage` and `TestMapView` (and all the objects in TestMapViewRenderer) will be destroyed when I navigate back to `MainPage`. However, when I set a break point on `Dispose()` in the renderer and navigate back to `SecondPage` or `MainPage` in , it never gets hit.

My questions:

1. Are the `SecondPage`, `TestMapPage`, `TestMapView` and all the other objects in the view and view renderer like `MapboxMap` kept somewhere when I go back to `MainPage`?
2. When are pages and views destroyed/disposed of?
3. If those page objects are kept somewhere until the application shuts down, is it normal behaviour?
4. If not normal behaviour, how do I fix it?

I'm worried about memory leak...

`MainPage.xaml.cs`

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    // ...
    private async void OnGoToSecondPageClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage());
    }
}
```

`SecondPage.xaml.cs`

```cs
public partial class SecondPage : ContentPage
{
    // ...
    private async void OnMapShowClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new TestMapPage());
    }
}
```

`TestMapPage.xaml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MapTest"
             x:Class="MapTest.TestMapPage">
    <StackLayout Margin="5">
        <local:TestMapView
            x:Name="map"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

`TestMapView.cs`

```cs
public class TestMapView : View { }
```

`TestMapViewRenderer.cs`

```cs
public partial class TestMapViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<TestMapView, Android.Views.View>
{
    private MapboxMap map;

    public TestMapViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context) {}

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TestMapView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        // ...
        if (Control == null)
        {
            var mapView = new MapView(Context);
            SetNativeControl(mapView);
            mapView.GetMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    public void OnMapReady(MapboxMap map)
    {
        this.map = map;
        this.map.SetStyle(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.mapbox_style_satellite), this);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // A breakpoint never hits on this line. Why?
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: FYI, see related question [Dispose Xamarin Forms Views/Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61922118/199364).  Also, be sure to call `GC.Collect/GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers` in your testing. (You probably won't want to do that in production - forcing GC too often in any GC system can be counter-productive.)

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know;

1. No, on each navigation you create new page instances, so, the page is created and kept in memory by .NET itself, once garbage collection hits a certain threshold, the memory will be free. Until then, the pages are in memory, but not meant to use somewhen in the future.
2. When GC decides, the Xamarin/MAUI doesn't care about views.
3. Unfortunately, yes.
4. It's normal, you can overcome by using what @ToolmakerSteve refers.